# iOS6 Orientation Still Rotating even when told not to

Tags: ios, ios6, screen-orientation

I seem to be having difficulties with my iOS Application.

It's deployment target is iOS5.0, however I am using the iOS 6.0 SDK.

In my View Controller I have:

```
-(NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;
}

- (UIInterfaceOrientation)preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation
{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;
}

-(BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation
{
    return (toInterfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);
}
```

This works fine when running in the iOS5 simulator.
The view will not rotate to LandScape or upside down.

However, in the IOS6 Simulator (and on a Device), it will continue to rotate.

I have used `NSLog` to check that `-supportedInterfaceOrientations` does get called and it does, twice, however it still rotates to LandScape (right or left)

What am I doing wrong?

I've also extended the `UINavigationController` (My Root View Controller) to include this:

```
@implementation UINavigationController (Rotation_IOS6)

-(BOOL)shouldAutorotate
{
    return [[self.viewControllers lastObject] shouldAutorotate];
}

-(NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{    
    return [[self.viewControllers lastObject] supportedInterfaceOrientations];
}

- (UIInterfaceOrientation)preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation
{
    return [[self.viewControllers lastObject] preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation];
}

@end
```

But with still no success.

### Edit

As per matt's answer. I also needed to extend the UITabBarController with a similar implementation to my UINavigationController and that worked.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem could be that you have a navigation interface. Do you? If so, you need to subclass UINavigationController and use an instance of that subclass as your navigation controller. In that subclass, *that* is where you implement `supportedInterfaceOrientations`. So too for any parent view controller (e.g UITabBarController).

The reason is that the iOS 6 way of thinking about rotation is *completely* different from iOS 5. Nothing you think you know from iOS 5 applies any more. In iOS 6 we start at the level of the application itself and work our way down by way of the app delegate to the root view controller or other full screen view controller (e.g. a presented view controller) and *stop*. A parent no longer consults its children.

Moreover, the application itself (by way of the info.plist or the app delegate) must list *every* orientation that *any* part of the application can *ever* assume; view controllers can only ask for a *subset* of those.

See the release notes:

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#releasenotes/General/RN-iOSSDK-6_0/_index.html

However, note that this sentence is a lie:

> For compatibility, view controllers that still implement the shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation: method do not get the new autorotation behaviors

On the contrary, in iOS 6 the older autorotation methods are ignored completely; everybody gets the new autorotation behaviors. It is not "opt-in".

Comment: Bingo! I didn't know that the UITabBar would also effect the Autorotation - I extended UITabBar and Boom it worked!

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want the app to ever rotate you can remove landscape from your supported interface orientations in your info.plist and that should do it.

Otherwise you need to tell your root view controller to look to its children for orientation information.

Answer (score 0):

Check your project settings and info.plist they have a higher priority than the app delegate.
make sure that only the orientations you want are selected