# Do "Supported Interface Orientations" have precedent?

Tags: ios, objective-c, autorotate

I'm developing an app and I would like one screen to auto-rotate to landscape.

This will be the only rotating screen in the app.

I'm trying to find the easiest way of doing this.

If I set the supported orientations in the build summary page (i.e. with the toggle buttons) so that it is just portrait. Can I then override this in the code for the screen I want to auto-rotate?

Or do I have to do it the other way round?  i.e. support all orientations and then disable for all the screens I don't want to rotate?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Or do I have to do it the other way round? i.e. support all orientations and then disable for all the screens I don't want to rotate?

Yes. You must list for the Info.plist *all* the orientations you will support. Then limit particular view controller orientations with `supportedInterfaceOrientations`. Your one landscape view controller must be presented, i.e. use a "modal" segue or call `presentViewController:animated:`.

My answer here may be useful:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/13755923/341994

and my answer here:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/15301322/341994

Comment: Are they the same if there is only one view controller?

Answer (score 0):

Add an observer to the viewDidLoad method of the view you want to rotate like this :

```
[[UIDevice currentDevice] beginGeneratingDeviceOrientationNotifications];
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]
 addObserver:self selector:@selector(orientationChanged:)
 name:UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification
 object:[UIDevice currentDevice]];
```

and then set the views according the the view you want to change inside the **orientationChanged** method like this :

```
- (void) orientationChanged:(NSNotification *)note{
UIDevice * device = [UIDevice currentDevice];
switch(device.orientation)
{
    case UIDeviceOrientationPortrait:

        break;
    case UIDeviceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown:

        break;
    case UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeLeft:

        break;
    case UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeRight:

        break;

    default:
        break;
  };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In iOS 6, the app supported orientations (stated in `Info.plist`) are AND'ed with the top view controller supported orientations, so in order to accomplish what you want, you need to declare support for every orientation in `Info.plist`, and then override the `supportedOrientations:` method in the view controllers where you don't want rotation to take place, for example:

```
- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;
}
```